# In mobile view image is not remain responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

**This is my desktop code**

Hero is a class of banner in which all the  thing are written.

[In Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnbsR.png)

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  background: url('../img/banner.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 110px;
  min-height: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.hero h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.hero h1 span {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #e8f380;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e8f380;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 3;
}

.mouse {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 26px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px solid #e8f380;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -26px;
}
.mouse span {
  display: block;
  margin: 6px auto;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #e8f380;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: scroll;
  animation-name: scroll;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">

    <h1><span>Welcome to</span><br>Navigation</h1>

    <div class="mouse">
        <span></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

**After adding some media query**

[In mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlgfl.png)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 412px){
  .hero{
    background: url('../img/smallbanner.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
}
```

**This is my all code**
After using media query I still not get appropriate image in mobile view. Image still going down in mobile view.

I've tried all media query and also small banner image but still it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-size: contain; or background-size: cover;
    .hero {width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background-size: contain` instead of `cover`.

Check [this source](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for more information.

Also, try to mix settings in `background` property, like setting it `bottom center` instead of `center center`.

Comment: After adding contain instead of cover cover becomes small. like bootstrap  container.